# the required framework Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.appx failed to install

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova

I'm very new to Visual Studio and am trying to build an windows app.
I developed an App and build it with cordova/Phonegap for Android and iOS.

When trying to build an App for windows, I get this Error:

> Error     DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\1.0\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.appx"
>   failed to install.
>
> Fehler 0x80070002: Beim Vorbereiten der
>   Verarbeitung der Anforderung konnte die Erweiterung
>   "windows.stateExtension" aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht
>   registriert werden: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
>
> translation:
>   Error 0x80070002: During prepare the processing of the requirement, the extansion "windows.stateExtension" couldnt be registered caused by this Error: The system couldnt find the file

I don't understand it... under the Error path I got an file named Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.appx...

I don't know or understand what is still missing or why the error says its not there. Thanks for any help

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using when you're trying to build your app?

Comment: @Jordan Matthiesen Im using Windows 8.1

Comment: Does the file mention exist on disk? If not, you should do a VS repair. This seems like a bad install rather than any problem with your project.

Comment: @LindaZ WinJS.2.0.appx this file exist. I dont know what this "windows.stateExtension" is but I couldnt find this one. I dont think that  is an file. But I´ll try to reinstall VS and then we will see what happen.

Comment: Did reinstalling VS fix this issue?

Comment: @DanielJacobson no it doesnt help to reinstall VS.

Comment: @Blank can you try uninstalling your own WinJS app and then re-installing through Visual Studio F5?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, can you try the below:

Open File -> New -> Project -> Templates -> Other Languages -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows 8 and click on 'Install Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools'.